# Las palabras provenientes del caló, ¿están únicamente presentes en el castellano de España?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, españa, caló

Vi [un tweet](https://twitter.com/Pablo_Iglesias_/status/734690771123773440) en el que se menciona el glosario de un libro, donde se explica el significado de palabras usadas coloquialmente en Madrid, España.

Yendo palabra por palabra, veo que unas cuantas tienen su origen en el [idioma caló](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_cal%C3%B3): *chorar*, *camelar*, creo que también *julái*, etc. Después he ido recordando que el castellano de España tiene bastantes más palabras con este origen: *chaval*, *chungo*, *churumbel*, *pirarse*.

En vista de esta gran cantidad de palabras de pura jerga, me pregunto: ¿son estos términos conocidos solamente en España o han sido también adaptados en las variantes del castellano habladas en América del Sur y Central?

Comment: No parece muy antojadizo cuando el [wiccionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chavo) propone que [_chavo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8fvlroy|8fyCpPs) en su significado de niño venga del caló (a través o no de _chaval_). Esa palabra es usada al menos desde México hasta Centroamérica y se entiende en toda AL (tal vez hasta en Brasil) gracias a [El Chavo del 8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Chavo_del_8), una popular comedia mexicana de los 70 y 80.

Comment: En la página que enlazas hay un link a [palabras del español culto y coloquial provenientes del caló](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Palabras_del_espa%C3%B1ol_culto_y_coloquial_provenientes_del_cal%C3%B3) que especifica el país en el que se usa cada una. Algunas palabras como *chorar, chabón, chingar, chor(e)ar, choro* o *curda* se usan en varios países fuera de España. ¿Preguntas por los términos que enumeras o por palabras caló en general?

Comment: @Yay interesante, no me había fijado en ese Anexo de la Wikipedia. Me gustaría conocer de una forma algo general hasta qué punto el castellano de Latinoamérica ha ido captando palabras del caló. No me consta la presencia de gitanos a gran escala en esa zona, por lo que la primera impresión es que las palabras que haya allí será porque ya se habían introducido en el castellano de España antes de la colonización. Sin embargo, puede ser bonito ver qué flujos y en qué forma (y a través de qué variantes, como el lunfardo que comenta Rodrigo).

Comment: Ninguna de esas palabras se usa en Colombia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que los gitanos llegaron a la Península Ibérica en el siglo XV, y que la integración cultural no ocurre en tan poco espacio de tiempo, es lógico que el castellano de Sudamérica incluya muchas menos palabras de origen caló en comparación con la península.

Comment: No me parece muy científico. En el siglo XV. todavia no existia tanta diferencia.

Answer (score 2):

En Chile usamos al menos estas tres palabras derivadas del caló: **chamullar** (engañar, hablar mucho), **chorear** (robar) y **gil** (tonto). Las tres nos llegaron desde el lunfardo argentino, probablemente en letras de tangos. Me consta que son habituales en el habla coloquial chileno, y probabemente también lo sean todavía en Argentina. Y por otra parte la palabra **chavo** (niño) es casi un ícono mexicano. Es decir, no habrá mucha variedad en Latinoamérica, pero sí hay un par de ejemplos bien relevantes.

Comment: Caramba, ninguna de ellas es conocida en España (o al menos a mí no me suenan, más allá del _gil...ipollas_ y _chorar_ -sin la "e"). ¿Por lo que tengo entendido, el lunfardo es asociado a gente de clase baja. ¿Puede que éstos tuvieran origen gitano en algún caso?

Comment: El lunfardo es una mezcolanza de lenguas y dialectos de las minorías rioplatenses. Probablemente no recibió influencia directa del caló, sino de hablantes inmigrantes españoles de clase baja que cuando llegaron (alrededor del 1900) ya usaban esas palabras.

Comment: Un ejemplo de como usamos "gil" en Sudamérica: el mensaje de Pepe Mujica, ex presidente de Uruguay, a los delincuentes juveniles: "No seas _gil_ nabo de mierda. Vas a terminar como una rata de cárcel".

Comment: Caramba, el ejemplo es bastante bestia. En España una frase así tendría una connotación muy, muy mala. Usar _mierda_ en un ambiente no informal es rarísimo. También entiendo que es Pepe Mujica, con un lenguaje muy cercano y en un contexto muy concreto. Además, ¿qué es _nabo_?

Comment: "Nabo" es tonto, es típico de los argentinos (aunque Mujica es uruguayo). La frase se hizo famosa por lo coloquial. En realidad, "de mierda" no es tan fuerte, me imagino que es algo parecido a "puñetero" o "del carajo", aunque, claro, no es de lo más normal en boca de un presidente.

Comment: Los tres ejemplos citados siguen en pleno vigor en Argentina, y también *chabón* (tratamiento genérico como "tipo"), *curda*, *bufarra* (< *bujarra*), *curro* pero con el doble sentido de "engaño" y "trabajito secundario", y *payo* = "persona rubicunda".

Comment: Gil y chavo son conocidas pero no usadas en Colombia. El resto nunca antes las había oído.