# Significado de "conocal" o "colocal"

Tags: modismos, definiciones, expresiones, significado, españa

En España he oido varías veces la expresión "Muy bien colocal" como respuesta al saludo - pregunta "¿Qué tal?", y no lo acabo de comprender. La primera vez supuse que había entendido mal y que en realidad habían dicho "Muy bien, **colosal**" lo que si tiene sentido para mi. Sin embargo, las veces siguientes que lo he oido estoy seguro de que no existía el sonido "s": era "**colocal**" o "**conocal**".

He consultado el diccionario de la Real Academia, pero no recoge ninguna de las dos palabras - lo más parecido que he encontrado es [ocal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QqUh8Qp), pero la definición que ofrece (Dicho especialmente de algunas frutas, como la pera y la manzana: Muy gustosas y delicadas.) tampoco parece tener sentido.

¿Alguna idea del significado de la expresión?

Comment: Yo, español, nunca oí esta frase. ¿En qué zona de España lo oíste?

Comment: @fedorqui: sobre todo en Madrid y alguna vez en Cuenca

Comment: Curioso, googleé "muy bien colocal" y no me salió ningún resultado. Me deveno los sesos pensando en alguna [expresión similar típica de Madrid](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16932/1674) pero no me sale nada. Por cierto, ¡bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Que antes se me olvidó decirlo :)

Comment: Lo que sí veo es algún resultado con "muy bien con Ocal". Ocal es una empresa que parece que produce alimentos, por lo que lo mismo viene de algún anuncio que salía por la tele o la radio hace años.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues parece que te encontraste con personas mayores que repetían una frase muy popular en la España de los años 40 y 50, proviniente de un anuncio publicitario de la marca OKAL:

> **Hola, ¿qué tal?, muy bien con OKAL.**

[image]

Leído en [Los 10 mejores Jingles de todos los tiempos (V)](http://grupographic.com/los-10-mejores-jingles-de-todos-los-tiempos-v/%20A%C3%B1o%201940-1950):

> A mitad del siglo XX, prácticamente todos los medicamentos eran multiusos, todavía no había llegado a los mercados la célebre “penicilina americana”. La mítica tableta de Okal era el producto estrella del momento.
>   La melodía y el slogan tardarían poco en convertirse en los más populares, **la canción fue cantada miles de veces por la radio y el slogan “Hola, ¿Qué tal?, muy bien con OKAL” era repetido una y otra vez por el público de aquellos años**.
>   Una campaña que aún hoy perdura en la memoria de los más mayores, dejo una huella imposible de borrar en las páginas de la historia de la publicidad.

También lo documentan en Memorias del Viejo Pamplona - [Aquellos anuncios publicitarios (1940-1990). 2ª Parte](http://memoriasdelviejopamplona.blogspot.com.es/2015/01/aquellos-anuncios-publicitarios-1940.html):

> Entre los productos farmacéuticos, parafarmacéuticos y de cuidado personal estarían los siguientes el histórico analgésico Okal (Hola, que tal. Muy bien con Okal), el antitusígeno Iniston (Abuelo, ¿has visto el Iniston?), la loción antipiojos Filvit (Filvit champú, Filvit, mama, porque más vale Filvit que tenerse que arrascar), el reconstituyente Micebrina (una al día), (...).
>   Puedes ver en [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xi7uxl_contra-todo-dolor-tableta-okal_shortfilms) otro de los anuncios de esta compañía.

Yo nunca oí esta frase en mis treinta y pico años de vida, supongo que se está perdiendo...

Comment: Yo tampoco la he escuchado nunca, pero siempre son interesantes estas cosas :)

Comment: Es realmente curioso, y aún más que el medicamento se escriba con "k". Gracias !

Comment: @user13560 sí, absolutamente. Lo que se me ocurre es que este medicamento servía para que la gente estuviera bien, lo que en inglés sería _OK_. Al añadirle el _-al_ típico de los medicamentos, lo dejaron en _OKal_. Digo yo... es una hipótesis :)