# ¿Qué es una "kelly" (referido a una persona) en este artículo?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, españa, palabras-raras

El artículo [El precio de trabajar en Magaluf](http://www.elmundo.es/baleares/2018/08/17/5b76739146163f10188b45d8.html) de El Mundo habla sobre una trabajadora de servicio de limpieza de un hotel de la localidad de Calvià donde está el *resort* de Magaluf y de las desdichas (o lo difícil y penoso) de su trabajo.

En el artículo se lee:

> Esta **kelly** va a tardar en olvidar lo que ha vivido en el trabajo ya que, a su entender, la gente que se hospeda en un hotel ubicado en Magaluf no se «comporta igual que en su casa».
>
> [image]

Entiendo que "kelly" se refiere a esta señorita que trabaja en el servicio de limpieza, pero no sé qué significa.

¿Qué significa `kelly` cuando se refiere a una persona<sup>1</sup>?

---

1- Digo una persona porque veo que lo usan para referirse a una persona. No sé si tiene significados adicionales y/o distintos aplicado a otras cosas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vas bien encaminado: *kelly* es un neologismo coloquial para referirse a las camareras de piso, especialmente limpiadoras de habitaciones de hoteles.

El término ha cogido mucho vuelo últimamente, y así lo atestigua el hecho que la asociación que las agrupa y representa en los medios de comunicación se llame precisamente así: *Las Kellys*.

En su web explican en [*Quiénes somos*](https://laskellys.wordpress.com/quienes-somos/):

> Las Kellys es una Asociación a nivel español de camareras de piso (lee el manifiesto). El nombre “Las Kellys” proviene de un popular juego de palabras: “la Kelly, la que limpia”; en nuestro caso limpiamos hoteles.

Por tanto, *kelly = **que li**mpia*.

En España están muy presentes en las noticias, especialmente alrededor del verano. Esto es porque su trabajo de limpiar habitaciones de hoteles es muy común en este país con tanto turismo. Dada la crisis y desempleo del país, es fácil ver que sus condiciones laborales y de precariedad son altas, por lo que suelen reivindicar mejoras salariales, de conciliación, etc. De ahí que su nombre *las que limpian* tenga esa fuerza de introducir de forma algo humorística su rol: "son esas personas invisibles que limpian para que el turista tenga todo bonito, sin que a nadie le importe quiénes son y en qué condiciones limpian".

Comment: Qué raro, para mí queli siempre ha tenido un significado muy diferente: *casa*.  ¿La pronunciación de kelly sería *quelí* ya que es *que **lim**pian* o se pronuncia igual a que la queli/keli de toda la vida?

Comment: @guifa uy es que lo de _queli_ para casa es muy de los ochenta, es un mundo y [poca gente lo entendería hoy en día](https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/95509/0/kelifinder/lectores/desactualizados/) :) En cuanto a la pronunciación, sí, efectivamente es _queli_ de toda la vida. Sospecho que se ha cogido el término con un toque anglófono por el hecho de que muchas de las _kellys_ suelen ser del mundo hispanoamericano, más propenso a coger palabras así.

Comment: Es que soy hijo de los ochenta jaja (bueno, literalmente nací en ellos jajaja por lo menos).  Pero vamos.... aquel artículo dice que también expresiones como «mola mazo» o «guay» están desfasadas?  ¿Acaso no han pasado mucho tiempo por las tierras madrileñas?  Siguen muy vivas.

Comment: @guifa lo de _guay_ se oye mucho. Yo mismo lo digo, si bien empiezo a tener la sensación de que es demasiado juvenil para mis incipientes canas (también soy de los ochenta jaja). En cuanto a _mola mazo_, lo asocio efectivamente a las tierras madrileñas y sus _tronco_, _dabuten_ y compañía. Me recordó [un tuit que referencié hace un tiempo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16932/1674) que seguro que despierta muchas palabras que tienes allí en la retina.

Comment: @guifa "Queli", con el significado de "hogar", es de género masculino. "Queli", como apócope de "el/la que limpia" es del género del limpiador. Que, pese a lo que dice la respuesta, no necesariamente ha de serlo de hoteles.

Comment: @NunoAndré llevas razón. Actualicé, pues me dejé llevar por lo más común, que es que sean limpiadoras de habitaciones de hoteles.

Comment: @NunoAndré El diccionario de María Moliner lo recoge como sustantivo femenino.  Yo siempre lo he usado como tal, aunque debido a su terminación en *i* además de que casi siempre se usa en la secuencia «me queli» o «tu queli», tampoco es preciso saber el género.  Mirando en google, veo ejemplos de ambos con "nuestro/a" por lo que podemos decir que no está bien fijado el género.

Comment: @guifa Qué curioso. La verdad es que yo siempre lo he oído como masculino, incluso como "el quel" o "el quelo", y la única referencia pública que consigo recordar es una canción de la banda O'funk'illo que se titula "Nos vamos pal keli". Puede que incluso el género de "queli" siga algún tipo de distribución geográfica.