# ¿Cómo debería traducirse correctamente el título de la película "The Help"?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

A la película en idioma inglés titulada "[The Help](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454029/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)" le dieron 2 traducciones para el idioma español. Así:

Para España se llama "[Criadas y señoras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Help)"
Para Hispanoamérica es "[Historias cruzadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Help)"

¿Qué tienen que ver esos títulos con la expresión "The Help"?

¿"The Help" se podría traducir como "La ayuda" o "La asistencia"?
¿O será que "The Help" es algún tipo de modismo?

¿Alguna idea?

Esta problemática proviene de las empresas encargadas de la distribución y promoción de películas en España y los países de Hispanoamérica, las cuales  escogen, vaya a saber con qué criterio, unos títulos que poco o nada tienen que ver con el título original y además tampoco hay unidad de criterio ya que escogen títulos diferentes si la película se exhibe en España o si es en los países hispanoamericanos.

Comment: Yo propongo ["Las Kellys"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27099/5481)

Comment: @Diego, ¿qué es "kellys"?

Comment: El link enlaza a una pregunta previa de este Stack ["¿Qué es una “kelly” (referido a una persona) en este artículo?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27099/5481): `kelly es un neologismo coloquial para referirse a las camareras de piso, especialmente limpiadoras de habitaciones de hoteles.[...] El nombre “Las Kellys” proviene de un popular juego de palabras: “la Kelly, la que limpia”; en nuestro caso limpiamos hoteles` Creo que no aplica del todo a responder tu pregunta (por eso es un comentario y no respuesta), pero como es una pregunta relacionada quise ponerla.

Comment: @Diego nunca había oido o leido la expresión "kelly" y por lo que veo es muy de España; la verdad no lo he escuchado en Colombia para referirse al personal que ordena y asea las habitaciones en los hoteles. Bien podría ser título para la película en cuestión con un tinte de humor!

Comment: "The help" can be *the servant* or *servants*.  So, in principle you could translate it as "los sirvientes."  But if you want to leave it vague, such that it would work for singular or plural, you could put *Sirvientes*.  I guess this is what Pablo is expressing with *servidumbre* -- but I don't like *servidumbre* because to me it suggests "servitude" -- a concept, not a class of people.  Note: "the help" goes farther than a type of work or a type of employee.  It is very much a *class*.  Almost a *species* -- I'm talking about what people who would use that word mean by it.

Comment: If you want to convey the *attitude* that "the help" expresses, then, if it's singular, I'd say "La Muchacha."  This denigrates an adult woman, in the same way "the help" does. // By the way, there are more respectful terms in English than "the help," such as *housekeeper*, *cleaning woman*.  A cleaning woman does not work in the same house every day, a housekeeper does -- that's the difference.  Nowadays I think it would be more common to say "the woman who cleans my house once a week" than "cleaning woman."  Still, if she comes every day, she's a *housekeeper*.

Comment: @aparente001 that's an interesting insight. My mum read this book and explained me that the book history happens in southern states of USA by the 60s, where the help would be a black woman so they were socially "below" the people they were serving to. So from that point of view, using "sirviente" would really match this meaning, since the help would very much _serve_ the people.

Comment: El tema de las traducciones siempre ha tenido su miga. Especialmente sangrante me pareció la traducción de _The eternal sunshine of the spotless mind_, que en España se conoce como _Olvídate de mí_. Un drama. Sea como fuere, las traducciones obedecen a temas de promoción y otro sinfín de variables que se escapan del ámbito de este sitio, por lo que creo que lo importante aquí es aclarar el ámbito en el que se usa _The help_ en el libro y la película y buscar cuál sería su correspondencia más directa en el castellano.

Comment: @fedorqui - your mother's explanation sounds good, except that the term "the help" covers any race of servant.  It's true that in certain places and periods the "help" tended to be African American, but the term itself is actually broader than that.  Also note that if a family has several servants, there may be one or more male servants and those would be part of "the help" also.  I can well imagine a well-heeled Bostonian of a few generations ago referring to "the help," which could well have been recent Irish immigrants, who were white.  Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @aparente001 ok, I see. But in the context of Mississippi in late 60s, what would the meaning be? Will it refer to African American ones?

Answer (score 5):

El sustantivo inglés *help* no sólo significa "ayuda" o "asistencia" sino también, en ciertas colocaciones, "servidumbre". En particular, la frase nominal *the help* usada sin modificadores y en su debido contexto sólo puede significar eso.

La palabra *help* funciona en este caso como un colectivo. Por lo tanto traducir *The Help* como "La servidumbre" sería la opción más correcta. Como título para una película quizá no suene tan bien pero es cuestión de gustos.

Estaba pensando en usos de la expresión y recordé uno muy gracioso que aparece en la segunda película de *Los locos Addams*. Merlina (Wednesday en el original) está de campamento y le llega una carta de la familia avisándole que el tío Lucas (Fester en el original) va a casarse con la niñera (que el matrimonio Addams contrató para cuidar a su hijo menor, Pubert). Esto es terrible para Wednesday porque la niñera es una trepadora y además... amor, pero otra de las niñas parece horrorizada más bien por la diferencia de clase. Me da la impresión que *the help* tiene un tono levemente peyorativo en cualquier caso.

> **Wednesday:** This is the worst thing that has ever happened in the
>   history of human events. Uncle Fester's getting married.
>
> **Gary:** A wedding? But that's great news!
>
> **Amanda:** To whom?
>
> **Wednesday:** The nanny.
>
> **Amanda:** Get out of the cabin. I mean, I'll kill myself. *The help?*
>
> **Becky:** I'm sure she's a very nice lady.
>
> **Amanda:** I think that's disgusting. I think their whole family's like
>   some weird medical experiment. I think they're like, circus people.

Answer (score 4):

Según aparece en el Cambridge Dictionary

**[the help](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/help)** old-fashioned
​

> a person or the people employed to work in someone's home doing
> cleaning, cooking, caring for children, etc.
>
> ES: Persona o personas empleadas para trabajar en la casa de alguien limpiando, cocinando, cuidando a los niños, etc.

Y consultando el Oxford

**[help](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/help)**

> A domestic employee. 
> ES: Un empleado **doméstico**

---

Por el lado español, consultando el diccionario de la R.A.E tenemos

[**servicio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XhXvJqs)

> 2. m. Conjunto de criados o sirvientes.
> 3. m. **servicio doméstico**.

Quizás "**El servicio**" sea lo más preciso y más ajustado al original inglés.

Y además entroncaría con un clásico del cine español [¡Cómo está el servicio!](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A1C%C3%B3mo_est%C3%A1_el_servicio!) protagonizado por Gracita Morales y dirigido por Mariano Ozores.

[image: ¡Cómo está el servicio!]

---

Por estudiar otras opciones, en la R.A.E encontramos las siguientes definiciones

**[criado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BFq6HFr)**

> 2. m. y f. Persona que sirve por un salario, y especialmente la que se emplea en el **servicio doméstico**.

**[asistente, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=416WFrl)**

> 10. f. Esp. Mujer que trabaja haciendo tareas **domésticas** en una casa sin residir en ella y que cobra generalmente por horas.

**[chacho, cha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8RxyimD)**

> 3. f. coloq. sirvienta (mujer que sirve como criada).

Nótese que esta última está marcada como coloquial, así que yo la descartaría pues no parece que "The help" se corresponda con ese matiz.

Creo que (Las) Asistentas o (Las) Criadas, serían igualmente válidos como traducción, ya sería tarea de los de marketing elegir el título más atractivo e incluir o no el determinante. Yo me quedaría con "**Criadas**", no muy alejado del que se escogió en España para la película.

Por último, yo descartaría "Las Kellys" principalmente porque su trabajo no se corresponde con los personajes protagonistas de la película, las cuales trabajan en casas particulares mientras que las Kellys identifican a trabajadoras de piso en hoteles.
Además "help" en "The help" no se corresponde con un apelativo coloquial ni un sobrenombre.

---

La última palabra entre ambas opciones, "Criadas" o "El servicio", la tendría la autora original del libro, Kathryn Stockett. Dada la historia, puede que estuviera de acuerdo en resaltar que sus protagonistas son mujeres; ya que "servicio" incluye una serie de empleos usual y tradicionalmente representados por hombres como mayordomo, jardinero o chofer, que no tienen presencia en la obra.

Comment: Yo iba a responder que "el servicio" me parecía la mejor opción, por eso te voto positivo y te recomendaría que pusieras esa opción arriba del todo del post, pues me parece la más acertada y la que debería destacarse más.

Comment: @Charlie Ok, gracias por el apunte. Editado.

Answer (score 2):

El problema aquí es que el título en inglés tiene un doble sentido que resulta difícil traducir al castellano.  Lo que están haciendo con estas traducciónes para España y para América Latina es tratar de captar el tema de la película de otra forma que traducir literalmente el nombre del inglés.

En inglés "The Help" puede significar "responsable doméstico" por un lado y "ayudar" por otro.  El segundo sentido simbológicamente podría respresentar la ayuda que dan más allá de las labores domésticas.

Implícitamente, los títulos creados en español ("Criadas y señoras" y "Historias cruzadas") representan el tema de la película lo cual es la vida cruzada de criadas y señoras.  El título de España es más directo mientras el de Hispanoamérica es más simbológico, y representa un deseo de no ofender las sensibilidades hispanoamericanas con referirse a "Criadas" como es película norteamericana.

Siempre hay que recordar que es importante poner atención al "marketing" cuando creando el título de una película...

Comment: Nótese que The Help tiene ese doble sentido que indicas pero no se identifica con el verbo sino con el sustantivo: la ayuda. Teniendo en cuenta que servicio también significa "favor que se hace a alguien", creo que mantiene ese doble sentido